# Cannot get angularJS templateUrl to resolve in shared module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is absolutely driving me insane. I have an angular module that is injected into various other apps. When I try to use `templateUrl` to a relative path in the shared module, I get a 404 error.

> angular.min.js:99 GET http://localhost:8001/modals/modal.html/
>   404 (Not Found)

This is my directory structure:

```
order-request
  |- modals
     |- modal.html
  |- index.js
  |- InitiateTransaction.js
```

index.js

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import InitiateTransaction from './InitiateTransaction';

export default angular
  .module('orders', [])
  .component('initiateTransaction', InitiateTransaction);
```

InitiateTransaction.js

```
export default {
  template: `<div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <div uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
        <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-flat btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
          Initiate Transaction <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="uib-dropdown-menu dropdown-menu text-left" role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
          <li role="menuitem"><a class="clickable" ng-click="$ctrl.open('subscription')">Subscription</a></li>
          <li role="menuitem"><a class="clickable" ng-click="$ctrl.open('redemption')">Redemption</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`,
  controller: class InitiateTransaction {
    constructor($scope, $uibModal) {
      this.$scope = $scope;
      this.$uibModal = $uibModal;
      this.modalInstance = null;
    }

    open(transactionType) {
      this.modalInstance = this.$uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: modals/modal.html',
        size: 'lg',
        scope: this.$scope
      });
    }
  }
};
```

I am not using webpack and have not been able to import html files at the top of InitiateTransaction.js

I've always understood templateUrl to look from the level of the index file for the module? Is this correct?

Is there something that I need to do in the app that injects this?

```
import '<some-working-path>/order-requests/index';

const app = angular.module('PortfolioApp', ['orders']);
```

Comment: Assuming you're using HTML5 mode, you would've needed to specify a `<base>` tag. Check your relative template path against this (i.e. `<base href="/">`).

Comment: did you check in developer tool's sources to see where modals folder is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually had to do with the bundling process. I needed to add the templates directory to my gulpfile.js.

Something like:

```
moduleConfig.init(require('gulp'), require('./package.json'), {
    templates: [
        moduleConfig.configDirs.sourceDir + '/modules/order-request/modals/**/*.html'
    ]
});
```